# Repa --- How to make a Read instance?

Tags: haskell, repa

What is the best way to make

```
type Configuration = Array DIM1 (Double, Double, Double)
```

an instance of Read? So later I could derive

```
data SimulationData = SD Configuration Double StdGen Int
```

to be an instance of Read too.

Comment: I suspect you can't make a "full" Read instance. Generally, important datatypes will already have Read instances if the author believes they make sense. The `Array` type in Repa has higher order functions inside its components - `Generator` and `Range` which cannot be made instances of Read. I'd imagine the correct thing to do is serialize / de-serialize your data into a simpler format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such an instance will be an [orphan instance](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance), which you should generally avoid. However, it's fairly simple to write it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Array.Repa (Array, Shape, Elt, Z(..), (:.)(..))
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R

instance Read Z where
  readsPrec _ r = do
    ("Z", s) <- lex r
    return (Z, s)

instance (Read tail, Read head) => Read (tail :. head) where
  readsPrec d =
    readParen (d > prec) $ \r -> do
      (tl, s) <- readsPrec (prec + 1) r
      (":.", t) <- lex s
      (hd, u) <- readsPrec (prec + 1) t
      return (tl :. hd, u)
    where prec = 3

instance (Shape sh, Read sh, Elt a, Read a) => Read (Array sh a) where
  readsPrec d =
    readParen (d > app) $ \r -> do
      ("Array", s) <- lex r
      (sh, t) <- readsPrec (app + 1) s
      (xs, u) <- readsPrec (app + 1) t
      return (R.fromList sh xs, u)
    where app = 10
```

If you use the `StandaloneDeriving` extension, the first two instances can be simplified:

```
deriving instance Read Z
deriving instance (Read tail, Read head) => Read (tail :. head)
```

These instances should probably be in repa itself; I just based them on the example instance given in [Text.Show](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html) and repa's `show` output. I suggest making a feature request on repa's [bug tracker](http://repa.ouroborus.net/), and putting these instances into a module of your program for now (unless you want to avoid orphan instances entirely, in which case you'll have to solve the problem another way altogether).

---

That said, you should probably consider simply converting your data to a list (with `toList`) and using that; it avoids the orphan instance, and shouldn't have any downsides. You might also want to consider using a "real" serialisation library like [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) if you're more interested in processing the data with code than having it be human-readable; `Read` is generally considered to be of rather limited use.

Comment: The `Array` type in Repa is made from a list of Regions which contain `Range` and `Generator`, both Range an Generator have higher-order functions as components so they can't really be made instances of Read.

Comment: @stephentetley: All a `Read` instance has to be able to do is parse the valid Haskell code that the corresponding `Show` instance outputs.

Comment: `show $ R.fromFunction (Z :. (10::Int)) (const 42)` = `"Array (Z :. 10) [42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0]"`, which my instance parses correctly.

Comment: Admittedly, repa's `Show` instance is breaking the rules here, as that code doesn't type, but that rule is frequently bent (e.g. `Data.ByteString.Char8` exports a `Show` instance for ByteStrings which only works if you turn on `OverloadedStrings`, and I think the `Show` instance for lazy ByteStrings actually uses unexported constructors).

Comment: @ehird: Requiring `Show` and `Read` to be semantically valid Haskell serves little practical purpose. Syntax matters, however, as it would otherwise be difficult to define well-behaved instances for container types like `[a]` which have to cooperate with the instances for the element type.

Comment: @hammar: Yes, that's a fair view. I consider `Show` basically only useful for debugging (which it's very useful for, of course), and `Read` only useful for toy programs, so I may value semantically valid instances more than others.

Comment: @ehird, there is a problem. I can't parse for example `Just arr`, it gives me "*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse", though parsing arrays themselves or tuples works.

Comment: @Yrogirg: This is a bug in repa's `Show` instance: it shows `Just arr` as `Just Array (Z :. 10) [...]`, without the required parentheses. Changing `readsPrec d = readParen (d > app) $ \r -> do` to `readsPrec d r = do` should make my instance work in this case, but unfortunately what repa is doing causes inherent ambiguity; you should report it as a bug.